# GCM example in android with ASP .net service

Tags: android, asp.net, google-cloud-messaging

I need example GCM in android with ASP .Net service. Can You share example about it?

Comment: This is an ideal search for Bing or Google.  StackOverflow is for specific programming problems.

Answer (score 1):

Check [Push notification on Androïd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25422150/push-notification-on-andro%C3%AFd/25422495#25422495)

Server can use GCM registration ID sent by device to communicate with Google Cloud Server.

Answer (score 0):

See here:
[Google Cloud Messaging Server Side Code in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11543527/google-cloud-messaging-server-side-code-in-c-sharp)

It's a simple HTTP POST where you need to pass in the correct set of parameters (JSON data and your APK and a registration key from what I remember). By using the libraries in the above link, or simply writing your own, you should be able to post messages to GCM and then have your Android client react to the messages that are posted by your service.